# Double precision when number converted from string

Tags: c#, string, casting, sql-server-2008-r2, double

I’m getting numbers from a database. Some are stored as `double` in the database and some are stored as `string`.

What I want to do is count the `decimal number` of caracters so : 345.34938 would give me a result of `5`.

As I said, some of my `double` come from the database as `double` and some as `string`. I’m wondering if there could be any kind of problem when `casting` the `string` numbers to `double`, hence giving me wrong result when trying to `count` the decimals.

I think I should be ok but I’m afraid that in some situations I’ll end up receiving wrong double numbers when they’re casted from the `string` (thinking about having 1.9999999 instead of 2.0, things like that)...

Is there any kind of risk that casting my number from `string` to `double` would give me strange result when stored as `double` in my application ? Am I being to frisky around that ?

Comment: You are missing a language tag...

Comment: Oh yeah, Thank you PhiLho ! Fixed !

Comment: Why do you want to count them? You obviously know the risks involved, so maybe there's another way to solve the real problem?

Comment: A double doesn't really have the concept of decimal digits. If that concept is important for you, use `decimal` or `string`.

Comment: @DStanley Actually, I'm guessing there could be a risk but I'm not sure... I have difficulty to see how a cast from string to double could be a problem... What are the cases in which there could be a problem... Do you have an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider converting the `string` representations to `System.Decimal` with the `decimal.Parse` method. Because for a `decimal` there's a much better correspondence between the value of the number and its string representation. Also, it can handle more digits.

A `System.Decimal` will preserve trailing zeros present in the string (like `"2.7500"`), which a `System.Double` will not.

But if your strings never have more than 15 digits in total (including digits before the decimal point `.`), your approach with `double` will probably work. But the exact number represented almost always differs from "what you see" with a `double`, so the number of decimal figures is to be understood as what `double.ToString()` shows...

Maybe it's easier to just use the string directly, like

```
int numberOfDecimals = myString.Length - (myString.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: I would use the `decimal.TryParse()` instead of `decimal.Parse()`, in case the parsing fails.

Comment: @Bob Very good idea. There might be cases, of course, where you can guarantee that it will parse, but if there's any doubt, certainly use `TryParse`.